# How we change last ptag of a paragarph with a <a> tag using php

Tags: php, preg-replace

```
<p class="more">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi ac cursus est, in auctor nibh. Vivamus scelerisque tempor cursus. Maecenas bibendum ex sollicitudin lectus consectetur semper. Sed a tortor id massa sagittis molestie. Nullam a hendrerit metus.</p>

<p class="more">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi ac cursus est, in auctor nibh. Vivamus scelerisque tempor cursus. Maecenas bibendum ex sollicitudin lectus consectetur semper. Sed a tortor id massa sagittis molestie. Nullam a hendrerit metus. <a class="toggle">read less</a></p>
```

What I've tried is as follows

```
$outputText = str_replace('<p>','<p class="more">',$outputText.'<p class="more"><a class="toggle">read less</a></p>');
```

Comment: Hello! Did you really just Lorem ipsum a SO question? Could you explain what it is that you are trying to do? You want to change the last ptag into an a tag? but u have it there already, so you want two closing a tags?

Comment: soory its just a paragraph description i have to two paragraph like <p>Some text..<p><p>some text..</p> i need to add a <a href=""></a> on last </p> tag like <p>Some text..<p><p>some text..<a href=""></a> </p>

Comment: Alright i see what you're saying now, i can try to answer this one :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to insert link in the end of last paragraph, you should use combination of  strrpos and substr_replace like this:

```
substr_replace($initialString,'<a class="toggle">read less</a>',strrpos($initialString,'</p>'),0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way that [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) works is like this:

```
str_replace("lookforthis", "replacewiththis", "withinthis");
```

What you are doing is not correct according to the functions spec, you are doing something like:

```
Look for: <p>
Replace with: <p class="more">
Within: $outputText (whatever this is) + <p class="more"><a class="toggle">read less</a></p>
```

You would need to do this:

```
$inputString = '<p class="more">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi ac cursus est, in auctor nibh. Vivamus scelerisque tempor cursus. Maecenas bibendum ex sollicitudin lectus consectetur semper. Sed a tortor id massa sagittis molestie. Nullam a hendrerit metus.</p>';
$outputString = str_replace('</p>','<a class="toggle">read less</a></p>',$string);

// $outputString will be
// <p class="more">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi ac cursus est, in auctor nibh. Vivamus scelerisque tempor cursus. Maecenas bibendum ex sollicitudin lectus consectetur semper. Sed a tortor id massa sagittis molestie. Nullam a hendrerit metus.<a class="toggle">read less</a></p>
```

Edit:

If there were two strings then you could do the following with preg_replace instead:

```
$inputString = "<p></p><p></p>";
// This will find the last occurance of </p> in a string and replace with <a href=""></a></p>
$outputString = preg_replace('#</p>$#', '<a href=""></a></p>', $inputString);
// Outputs:
// <p></p><p><a href=""></a></p>
```

Comment: Thanks but i need only to add the <a href=""></a> only on on the last paragraph </p> tag.

Comment: But this is exactly what will happen. Are you suggesting that there is more than one paragraph?

Comment: yes there is 2 paragraph but i need to add only on the last paragraph

Comment: Please can you edit into your question the desired output of all of this so as to avoid further confusion.

Comment: soory its just a paragraph description i have to two paragraph like <p>Some text..<p><p>some text..</p> i need to add a <a href=""></a> on last paragraph with </p> tag like <p>Some text..<p><p>some text..<a href=""></a> </p>